# (File export)Is it a correct code?[Need help]

Tags: android, file

(I'm beginning in the Android dev)
I want to export a file from /data/data.... to a directory in the SDCARD, here is my code:

```
public class Import extends Activity {
    private Context context;

    public void transfer(){ 
        context = getApplicationContext();
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/SDCARD/Carburant");
    dir.mkdirs();
    copyfile(context,"/data/data/carburant.android.com/files/","/SDCARD/Carburant/storeddata.dat");

}

    private void copyfile(Context context,String srFile, String dtFile){
        context = getApplicationContext();
        try{
          File f1 = new File(srFile);
          File f2 = new File(dtFile);
          InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
          OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);

          byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
          int len;
          while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
          }
          in.close();
          out.close();

          Toast.makeText(context, "Export effectué", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            Toast.makeText(context, "File Not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Echec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
        }
      }

    }
```

Edited: 1st try:

```
case R.id.importer:
            String name;
            String mark;
            Import myImport = new Import(this,name,mark);
            Import myImport(this, name, mark);
            myImport.transfer();
            return true;
```

i have an error on this line : `Import myImport(this, name, mark);`

```
Import cannot be resolved to a variable
The method myImport(Saves, String, String) is undefined for the type Saves
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you pasted? How doesn't it work?

Comment: @sarnold: no FC, but nothing happens! No export :\! an idea please ?

Comment: How is this code called? There is no onCreate method or any of the other Activity lifecycle methods. I'm not sure this class even needs to extend Activity.

Comment: there is no on create i think because i just want to make a transfer operation! but .... i don't know the exactly meaning of putting extends Activity or not :\ !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Import class as follows (remove extends Activity)...

```
public class Import {
    private Context context;
    private String name;
    private String mark;

    public Import(Context context, String name, String mark) {
        this.context = context;
        this.name = name;
        this.mark = mark;
    }

    // Your other methods here
}
```

In the Activity which you use to create an instance of your Import class use...

```
Import myImport = new Import(this);
```

samold's suggestion of using...

```
copyfile(context,"/data/data/carburant.android.com/files/",
    sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/SDCARD/Carburant/storeddata.dat");
```

...will probably work OK although I'm worried about your source path...

```
"/data/data/carburant.android.com/files/"
```

...the above doesn't make sense for two reasons. Firstly you're not specifying a source filename (only a directory path). Secondly, app data is stored in a path as follows...

```
/data/data/<package name>
```

...package name should be similar to com.mycompany.myApp - you have it the other way around (i.e., myApp.mycompany.com) so unless carburant.android.com really IS the name of your package this isn't going to work as that directory won't exist.

EDIT: When the user enters their name and car mark just save them as Strings, e.g.,

```
String name;
String mark;
```

Then construct the path to file as ...

```
"/data/data/carburant.android.com/files/" + name + "." + mark + ".settings.dat;
```

To use your Import class, don't use startActivity with an Intent (remember it's not an Activity now). In the code where you check for the button press, simply use...

```
Import myImport(this, name, mark);
myImport.transfer();
```

See my modified code example for the Import constructor to take the name and mark strings.

One more thing, remove the line where you have...

```
context = getApplicationContext();
```

...this isn't necessary and will cause problems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the path is 100% correct, my package name is exactly "carburant.android.com"! BUT you have reason that i just put a path(not a file), there is a problem that the file in the /data/data/carburant.android.com/files/ has not a constant name, every user will put his name and his car mark in the app and the file will be saved like name.mark.settings.dat ! How solving this problem ? Thanks

Comment: other thing please, where to put exactly Import myImport = new Import(this); ? "myImport" variable i'll not use it !i just have to tap to a menu button to "execute" the class code!case R.id.importer:
         Intent i = new Intent(this,Import.class);
            startActivity(i);
         return true;

Comment: i solved the half part of the problem now, but when i export the file i have a File Not Found exception ! Why? thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/SDCARD/Carburant");
dir.mkdirs();
copyfile(context,"/data/data/carburant.android.com/files/",
    "/SDCARD/Carburant/storeddata.dat");
```

You create the directories with the absolute path of the SD card prepended to `"/SDCARD/Carburant/"`, but when you call your `copyfile()` routine, you forgot the absolute path of the SD card.

Try this:

```
copyfile(context,"/data/data/carburant.android.com/files/",
    sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/SDCARD/Carburant/storeddata.dat");
```

Comment: @sarnold: you have reason but what can i do ? i can't make this!! : copyfile(context,"/data/data/carburant.android.com/files/",dir); So how doing it ? thank you for your help

Comment: @androniennn, heh, I forgot the culminating piece! Sorry. Edited.

Comment: @sarnold: i maked a toast if the operation is successfully accomplished, i edited the line with yours and the toast doesn't appears :( !

Comment: @androniennn, @David Caunt raised enough questions about how this code is being used, that I wonder if this routine is being called at all. Try putting another `Toast.makeText(...)` call immediately _before_ calling `copyfile()`, and one of the first operations _inside_ `copyfile()`, and make sure that this function is actually called at runtime.

Comment: @sarnold: well as you said the function is not called? why ? because the toast just after calling copyfile() doesn't appear ! but why it's not called ? :\ :\

Comment: @androniennn, I'd suggest looking into David's concerns about your class `extend`ing a potentially unrelated class. I don't know anything about Android application _design_; I just found inconsistent destination paths. :) Please edit your question to include the code that calls this class.

Comment: @sarnold: i have a stored data and by tapping in an "export" menu button, this class is "called" ! i'm not sure what to put also in place of "extends Activity)! when i remove it i have an error in all Context(no toast messages!) ! i tried to put also "extends the activit that it's coming from" and nothing!